# Find the first non-repeated character in a string

Tags: python, algorithm

I read of a job interview question to write some code for the following:

> Write an efficient function to find the first nonrepeated character in
>   a string. For instance, the first nonrepeated character in “total” is
>   'o' and the first nonrepeated character in “teeter” is 'r'. Discuss
>   the efficiency of your algorithm.

I came up with this solution in Python; but, I'm sure that there are way more beautiful ways of doing it.

```
word="googlethis"
dici={}

#build up dici with counts of characters
for a in word:
    try:
        if dici[a]:
            dici[a]+=1
    except:
        dici[a]=1

# build up dict singles for characters that just count 1 

singles={}
for i in dici:
    if dici[i]==1:
        singles[i]=word.index(i)

#get the minimum value

mini=min(singles.values())

#find out the character again iterating...

for zu,ui in singles.items():
    if ui==mini:
        print zu
```

Is there a more concise and efficient answer?

Comment: Go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Please come up with better titles... _"Job Interview: Write an algorithm"_ is about as non-specific as you can get. A title should help guide future users to a question (and hopefully an answer!)

Comment: @Ben thanks for editing...but i thing its kind of spacial...that this was asked in an interview...anyway...you are right in regard of the "be more specific" thing...

Comment: Is there an O(n) solution? just scan string once.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
In [1033]: def firstNonRep(word):
   ......:     c = collections.Counter(word)
   ......:     for char in word:
   ......:         if c[char] == 1:
   ......:             return char
   ......:         

In [1034]: word="googlethis"

In [1035]: firstNonRep(word)
Out[1035]: 'l'
```

**EDIT**: If you want to implement the same thing without using helpers like `Counter`:

```
def firstNonRep(word):
    count = {}
    for c in word:
        if c not in count:
            count[c] = 0
        count[c] += 1
    for c in word:
        if count[c] == 1:
            return c
```

Comment: is `Counter` ordered reliable? i don't think it is?

Comment: A Counter was my first thought too, but the question is asking for efficiency, and a Counter is a black box, making it hard to analyze the runtime performance.

Comment: @dm03514: `Counter` is not order preserving. But if you notice, I iterate through the characters in the word. So the first non-repeating character in the word is returned

Answer (score 2):

```
sorted(word,key=lambda x:(word.count(x),word.index(x)) )[0]
```

I think
or DSM's also consice

```
next(c for c in word if word.count(c) == 1)
```

which is marginally more efficient

```
>>> word = "teeter"
>>> sorted(word,key=lambda x:(word.count(x),word.index(x)) )[0]
'r'
>>> word = "teetertotter"
>>> sorted(word,key=lambda x:(word.count(x),word.index(x)) )[0]
'o'
>>> word = "teetertotterx"
>>> sorted(word,key=lambda x:(word.count(x),word.index(x)) )[0]
'o'
```

Comment: This has a pretty huge runtime. O(nlogn) for sorting and O(n) for each `word.count`. So, a total runtime of O(n^2 logn), which is very inefficient. I think my solution works in O(n) runtime

Comment: ehh yeah I was goin for consise :P

Comment: thats pretty concise though ;)

Comment: If we're going to be concise, why not `next(c for c in word if word.count(c) == 1)`?  [Very inefficient, of course.]

Comment: ok yeah that would work also :P I think that would actually be less inefficient than mine ... since it short circuits

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import defaultdict
word="googlethis"
dici=defaultdict(int)

#build up dici with counts of characters
for a in word:
    if dici[a]:
        dici[a]+=1
for a in word:
    if didic[a] < 2:
        return a
```

wouldn't that work?

Comment: I dont think it would guarantee a first match ... (what if there are 2 letters in the word that only occur once)

Comment: the `for a in word` loop should be ordered, correct? If I looped over the dictionary, you're correct, but I'm looping over the word, so it should be in order.

Comment: yead sorry my bad ... I didnt read it and thought you were iterating over the dict

Answer (score 2):

More elegant way

```
def NotRepeatingCharacter(s):
    for c in s:
        if s.find(c) == s.rfind(c):
            return c
    return '_'
```

Answer (score 1):

Question: 1st non-repeating character in a string

Method 1: making a count array

```
a = "GGGiniiiiGinaaaPrrrottiijayi"
count = [0]*256
for ch in a: count[ord(ch)] +=1
for ch in a :
    if( count[ord(ch)] == 1 ):
        print(ch)
        break
```

Method2: List comprehension

```
# 1st  non repeating character
pal = [x for x in a if a.count(x) == 1][0]
print(pal)
```

Method 3: dictionary

```
d={}
for ch in a: d[ch] = d.get(ch,0)+1
aa = sorted(d.items(), key = lambda ch  :ch[1])[0][0]
print(aa)
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Try the input "Entwicklerheld". Your algorithm returns E and it should return n.

Answer (score 0):

My solution. I can't speak to how efficient it is; I think it runs in n^2 time.

```
>>> def fst_nr(s):
...     collection = []
...     for i in range(len(s)):
...             if not s[i] in collection and not s[i] in s[i+1:]:
...                     return s[i]
...             else:
...                     collection+=[s[i]]
... 
>>> fst_nr("teeter")
'r'
>>> fst_nr("floccinaucinihilipilification")
'u'
>>> fst_nr("floccinacinihilipilification")
'h'
>>> fst_nr("floccinaciniilipilification")
'p'
>>> fst_nr("floccinaciniiliilification")
't'
>>> fst_nr("floccinaciniiliilificaion")
>>>
```

Any advice for a humble Stack noob?

Answer (score 0):

I think the worst case is O(n^2) but looks clear for me:

```
def firstNonRep(word):
    """the first non-repeating character in a string: "ABCA" -> B """
    for (i, c) in enumerate(word):
        residual = word[i+1:]
        if not c in residual:
            return c
```

Answer (score 0):

Python; O(N+N) I think.

```
def find_first_non_occuring(test_str):
    results = {}
    for letter in test_str:
        if letter in results.keys():
            if results[letter] == 1:
                results[letter] = results[letter]+1
        else:
            results[letter] = 1 

    for letter in test_str:
        if results[letter] is 1:
            return letter
test_str = 'afixuboshafe fafd weagdgdg'
print find_first_non_occuring(test_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Three lines of python code to get the solution:

```
word="googlethis"
processedList = [x for x in word if word.count(x)==1]
print("First non-repeated character is: " +processedList[0])
```

Or,

```
word="googlethis"
print([x for x in word if word.count(x)==1][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code traverses through the string only once. It's a simple and easy solution for the problem but at the same time the space complexity is compromised.

```
def firstNonRepeating(a):
    inarr = []
    outarr = []

    for i in a:
        #print i
        if not i in inarr:
            inarr.append(i)
            outarr.append(i)
        elif i in outarr:
            outarr.remove(i)
        else:
            continue
    return outarr[0]

a = firstNonRepeating(“Your String”)
print a
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we need the first non-repeating character, it is better to use OrderedDict from collections because dict does not guarantee the order of the keys

```
from collections import OrderedDict
dict_values = OrderedDict()
string = "abcdcd"

for char in string:
   if char in dict_values:
   dict_values[char] += 1
else:
    dict_values[char] = 1

for key,value in dict_values.items():
    if value == 1:
       print ("First non repeated character is %s"%key)
       break
    else:
       pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def non_repeating(given_string):
    try:
        item = [x for x in given_string[:] if given_string[:].count(x) == 1][0]
    except:
        return None
    else:
        return item

# NOTE: The following input values will be used for testing your solution.
print non_repeating("abcab") # should return 'c'
print non_repeating("abab") # should return None
print non_repeating("aabbbc") # should return 'c'
print non_repeating("aabbdbc") # should return 'd'
```

Answer (score 0):

def firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s):

for c in s:

if s.find(c) == s.rfind(c):

return c

return '_'

Answer (score 0):

```
input_str = "interesting"
#input_str = "aabbcc"
#input_str = "aaaapaabbcccq"


def firstNonRepeating(param):
    counts = {}        
    for i in range(0, len(param)):

    # Store count and index repectively
        if param[i] in counts:
            counts[param[i]][0] += 1
        else:
            counts[param[i]] = [1, i]

    result_index = len(param) - 1
    for x in counts:
        if counts[x][0] == 1 and result_index > counts[x][1]:
            result_index = counts[x][1]
    return result_index

result_index = firstNonRepeating(input_str)
if result_index == len(input_str)-1:
    print("no such character found")
else:
    print("first non repeating charater found: " + input_str[result_index])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# I came up with another solution but not efficient comment?
str1 = "awbkkzafrocfbvwcqbb"
list1 = []
count = 0
newlen = len(str1)
find = False


def myfun(count, str1, list1, newlen):

    for i in range(count, newlen):

        if i == 0:

            list1.append(str1[i])

        else:
            if str1[i] in list1:
                str1 = str1.translate({ord(str1[i]): None})
                print(str1)
                newlen = len(str1)
                count =0
                i = count
                list1.pop()
                myfun(count,str1,list1,newlen)
            else:
                pass

    if str1.find(list1[0], 1, len(str1)) != -1 :
        pass
    else:
        print(list1[0]+" is your first non repeating character")
        exit()


myfun(count, str1, list1, newlen)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Python3 solution

```
def findFirstUniqueChar(s):
    d = {}
    for c in s:
        if c in d:
            d[c] += 1
        else:
            d[c] = 1

    for c in s:
        if d[c] == 1:
            return s.index(c)
    return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using generator object**

```
def main(): 
    s = 'NETSETOSNETM' 
    print(next((c for c in s if s.count(c) ==1))) 
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

**Explaination :**

```
(c for c in s if s.count(c) ==1)
```

is a generator object returning character if the count of that character is only 1.

by calling the next method on that yields the 1st character

```
next((c for c in s if s.count(c) == 1))
```

**Alternate code snippet**

```
def get_first_nrc(s): 
    for c in s: 
        if s.count(c)==1: 
            yield c 
 
def main(): 
    gen = get_first_nrc 
    s = 'NETSETOSNETM' 
    print(next(gen(s))) 
 
if __name__=="__main__": 
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

The idea here is to initialize an array with some default value , for example 0. And when you come across a particular character in the string, you just increase the counter using the ASCII value of that character in the array you defined initially.

As you pass through the string, you have to update the respective counters for the character in the array. Now one will require to go through the array one more time, and check if there is any value which is equal to 1, if there is - Just return that character as a first non-repeated character in a given string.

```
class FindFirstUniqueChar
{
    private static char ReturnFirstUniqueChar(string sampleString)
    { 
        // Initialize a sample char array and convert your string to char array.           
        char[] samplechar = sampleString.ToCharArray();

        // The default array will have all value initialized as 0 - it's an int array. 
        int[] charArray = new int[256];

        // Go through the loop and update the counter in respective value of the array 
        for (int i = 0; i < samplechar.Length; i++)
        {
          charArray[samplechar[i]] = charArray[samplechar[i]] + 1;
        }

        // One more pass - which will provide you the first non-repeated char.
        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++)
        {

            if (charArray[samplechar[i]] == 1)
            {
                return samplechar[i];
            }
        }

        // Code should not reach here. If it returns '\0'
        // that means there was no non-repeated char in the given string. 
        return '\0';
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The First Unique char in given String is: " +                         
                          ReturnFirstUniqueChar("ABCA"));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I have provided just a sample code. It doesn't include error check and edge cases.
For those who are Interested to know the time complexity of the give algorithm - It is 
O(N) + O(N) = O(2N) which is nearly O(N). It does use an extra memory space. 
Your feedback is welcome.

Comment: Now, just for the fun - i would like to add one Question here. For example let's say String is "AAAAAAAAAABCA" - Come up with a way that in the second round of iteration through the string - Once you get the value at 0th Index,  you don't need to go through Index 1 to 9 as they are same char 'A', Do you think we can directly jump to char 'B' for our further findings?  Hint: you already have the counts for chars.

Answer (score -1):

In Java,
1)Create the  Character count hashmap.
  For each character,if there is no value stored in the character,set it to 1.
  Else increment the value of the character by 1 .

2)Then I Scanned the String for each character.
           Return character if the count in hashmap is 1 .
           If no character has count 1 ,then return null.

```
package com.abc.ridhi;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FirstNonRepeated {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(" Please enter the input string :");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = in.nextLine();
        char c = firstNonRepeatedCharacter(s);
        System.out.println("The first non repeated character is :  " + c);
    }

    public static Character firstNonRepeatedCharacter(String str) {
    HashMap<Character, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        int i, length;
        Character c;
        length = str.length(); 
        // Scan string and build hashmap
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            c = str.charAt(i);
            if (map1.containsKey(c)) {
                // increment count corresponding to c
                map1.put(c, map1.get(c) + 1);
            } else {
                map1.put(c, 1);
            }
        }
        // Search map in order of string str

        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            c = str.charAt(i);
            if (map1.get(c) == 1){
                return c;
        }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
str = "aabcbdefgh"
lst = list(str)

for i in [(item, lst.count(item)) for item in set(lst)]:
    if i[1] == 1:
        print i[0],
```

Answer (score -1):

```
enter code here
```

public class FirstRepeatingAndNonRepeatingElements {

```
/**
 * 
 * @param elements
 * @return
 */
private int firstRepeatedElement(int[] elements) {
    int firstRepeatedElement = -1;
    if(elements!=null && elements.length>0) {
        Set<Integer> setOfElements = new HashSet<>();
        for(int i=elements.length-1;i>=0;i--){
            if(setOfElements.contains(elements[i])) {
                firstRepeatedElement = elements[i];
            } else {
                setOfElements.add(elements[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return firstRepeatedElement;
}


private int  firstNonRepeatedHashSet(int [] elements)  {
    int firstNonRepatedElement = -1;
    Set<Integer> hashOfElements = new HashSet<>();
    if(elements!=null && elements.length>0) {
        for(int i=elements.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
            if(!hashOfElements.contains(elements[i])) {
                hashOfElements.add(elements[i]);
                firstNonRepatedElement = elements[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return firstNonRepatedElement;
}


/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FirstRepeatingAndNonRepeatingElements firstNonRepeatingElement = 
            new FirstRepeatingAndNonRepeatingElements();
    int[] input = new int[]{1,5,3,4,3,5,6,1};

    int firstRepeatedElement = firstNonRepeatingElement.
            firstRepeatedElement(input);

    System.out.println(" The First  Repating Element is "
            + firstRepeatedElement);


    int firstNonRepeatedElement = firstNonRepeatingElement.
            firstNonRepeatedHashSet(input);

    System.out.println(" The First Non Repating Element is "
            + firstNonRepeatedElement);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class FirstNonRepeatedCharacter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "sasasasafng";

        firstNonRepeatedCharacterUsingCollection(str);

    }

    private static void firstNonRepeatedCharacterUsingCollection(String str) {

        LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer> hm = new LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            char ch = str.charAt(i);
            if (hm.containsKey(ch)) {
                hm.put(ch, hm.get(ch) + 1);
            } else {
                hm.put(ch, 1);
            }
        }

        for (Character c : hm.keySet()) {
            if (hm.get(c) == 1) {
                System.out.println(c);
                return;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

By using LinkedHashset we can get insertion orderd.