# Reload automatic imports after %reset

Tags: python, ipython

If my IPython session has been running for too long ([see comments on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14511382/198633)), I have the urge to `exit()` and restart IPython to free up the memory that was occupied by all the variables in that session. However, the restart takes up valuable seconds which I find annoying (not that I couldn't learn to live with it, but I shouldn't have to).

I discovered the magic function `%reset` that kills all my variables (yay!), but in so doing also kills the names imported into my namespace. These include the automatic imports defined in `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/00-imports.py`, which are imports that I'd like performed when my IPython session starts.

Is there a way for me to re-run these imports (sort of like the `source` command in bash); or better yet, is there a version of `%reset` that kills my variables, but not the imports?

**Technical details**:

1. IPython version: 0.13.1
2. OS: MAC OS X 10.7.5 (Lion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your own magic function to

- Call reset
- Re import your imports

You could probably call it

```
%deset
```

Or something like that.

Everything you need to learn how to do it is [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html).

Comment: To get a list of imported modules you can do `from types import ModuleType;[s for s in globals() if isinstance(globals()[s], ModuleType)]`.  I suppose you could print the names formated as import statements and `exec` that, or use `__import__(module_name)`.